How to get double output from same filename with different names
I have a SQL case like:
Select Case 
  when filename like '%bbb%' then 'apple' 
  when filename like '%aaa%' then 'banan' 
  When filename like '%ccc%' then 'kiwi' 
  Else filename 
End

I have an output like; apple Banan Kiwi
I should add an SQL code with same filename, but output should have a different name. I need different output from filename 'bbb'.
This is what I tried:
Select Case 
  when filename like '%bbb%' then 'apple' 
  when filename like '%aaa%' then 'banan' 
  When filename like '%ccc%' then 'kiwi' 
  When filename like '%bbb%' then 'lemon' 
  Else filename 
End 

I need both apple and lemon in the output from filename 'bbb'.
Expected output:
apple 
Banan 
Kiwi 
Lemon

How can I modify the SQL code?

The question isn't clear, at least to me. Can you share your sample data and the result you're expecting to get from it?

Which SQL system are you using? I don't recognise that syntax.

What is the motivation to define 3 different cases for 'abc'?

join a table/cte with separate rows for Ac. Ad and Ae.

CASE statements work top to bottom, and each row only responds to the first condition that evaluates as true and then it stops processing against the remaining criteria.
For each row it tries the first WHEN. If it is true ('abc') then it responds with the THEN ('ac'), and then moves to the next row in the table. If it is false, then it tries the second WHEN etc.
In your case, the second and third WHEN will not get evaluated, as it already met the first WHEN condition.
In short, if you have multiple of the same condition to evaluate 3x WHEN 'abc', the first one will get used, the others will not get evaluated.
If 'abc' is true, the response cannot be 'ac', 'ad' and 'ae'. It can only be 'ac'.

0
Yes, that's what happening, I have all the time 'ac' as output, but how can I get 3 different output from 'abc'? (With or without case)

case is an expresssion, not a statement. (In stored procedures/PSM, there's a case statement for conditional execution of code.)

@user5873356 You cannot do what you want using a CASE statement. I suggest you create a look-up table or CTE containing the filename/partial filenames in the first column and the fruit name in the second column. Then join on filename to the first column in the lookup table. This will output you both apple and lemon when it matches to filename LIKE '%bbb%'
